# Select list in Manual Tabular form not displaying correct value

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

i am new to oracle apex and i have requirement to create a manual tabular form.
i've created it using collections, I've load the collection when the page loads. elements in collection are displayed as select list. inserting and updating works good. the only problem i have is when i select the value in selected list and update, the value is updating in database correctly but the same value is not displaying for that record. for ex;

( first three elements are selected list, descr is a text field)
empno empname dept  descr 
 1     John   10    abc
 1     john   10    xyz

where as in data base the values are

1  john 10  abc
2  mary 20  xyz

Comment: Show what you've done. How are you generating the select list?

Answer (score 0):

I see it's been a while, but have you considered re-loading the collection from the database, then refreshing the tabular form?